# Refresh GridView data

Tags: c#, jquery, webforms

In my first load of my `aspx` page, I have a `GridView` that are filled.

In my `ASPX` page I handle the click event on my radio button

```
    $("#ctl00_contentConteudo_rbBuscas_1").click(function () {
        $.get("../Gerenciar/ListaUsuarioProvisorio.aspx?Documentacao=s&r=" + Math.random(2), {}, function (data) {                
        });
    });
```

So, this force to pass in my page load again when my radio button is clicked.

**ASPX**

```
<div id="infoGrid" runat="server">
    <cc1:GridView ID="grdImoveis" CssClass="StyleGrid" Width="100%" runat="server" ShowHeader="false"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="dsGrid" BorderWidth="0px" GridLines="None"
        AllowPaging="True" EnableModelValidation="True" >
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" CssClass="EstiloDalinhaAlternativaGrid" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle CssClass="EstiloDalinhaGrid" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Nome" DataField="NomeCompleto" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Cargo" DataField="DescricaoCargo1" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Data Cadastro" DataField="DataHora" />
            <asp:TemplateField ControlStyle-CssClass="acoes_lista_imovel" HeaderText="Curso">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="acoes_lista_imovel">
                        <%# montaIcones(Eval("Usuario_Id").ToString())%>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </cc1:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsGrid" runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>
```

**CODE BEHIND**

In my code behind, my `PageLoad` just call my `CarregaLista` method, that fill my `GridView`

```
protected void CarregaLista()
        {            
                string documentacao = Request.QueryString["Documentacao"].ToString();

                if (documentacao.Equals("s"))
                {
                    string select = string.Empty;
                    select += "SELECT top 10 San_Credenciada.Apelido, San_Usuario.NomeCompleto, San_Usuario.Usuario_Id, San_Usuario.DescricaoCargo1, "
                        + "CONVERT(varchar, San_Usuario.DataHora, 103) AS DataHora "
                        + "FROM San_Usuario "
                        + "JOIN San_Credenciada "
                        + "ON San_Usuario.Credenciada_Id = San_Credenciada.Credenciada_Id "
                        + "WHERE San_Usuario.Excluido = 0 "                        
                        + "GROUP BY San_Credenciada.Apelido, San_Usuario.NomeCompleto, San_Usuario.Usuario_Id, "
                        + "San_Usuario.DescricaoCargo1, San_Usuario.DataHora "
                        + "ORDER BY San_Usuario.DataHora ASC ";

                    dsGrid.ConnectionString = c.Con;
                    dsGrid.SelectCommand = select;
                    dsGrid.DataBind();
                    grdImoveis.DataBind();
                    dsGrid.Dispose();
                }
            }
}
```

**WITH UPDATE PANEL**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
    <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" Text="Curso Básico Netimóveis" />
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Text="Buscar Lista de Presença" />
                <asp:RadioButton ID="rdBuscas" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="Click" Text="Curso Documentação Imobiliária" />
        <cc1:GridView ID="grdImoveis" CssClass="StyleGrid" Width="100%" runat="server" ShowHeader="false"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="dsGrid" BorderWidth="0px" GridLines="None"
            AllowPaging="True" EnableModelValidation="True" >
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" CssClass="EstiloDalinhaAlternativaGrid" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle CssClass="EstiloDalinhaGrid" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Nome" DataField="NomeCompleto" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Cargo" DataField="DescricaoCargo1" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Data Cadastro" DataField="DataHora" />
                <asp:TemplateField ControlStyle-CssClass="acoes_lista_imovel" HeaderText="Curso">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="acoes_lista_imovel">
                            <%# montaIcones(Eval("Usuario_Id").ToString())%>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </cc1:GridView>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsGrid" runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rdBuscas" />
        </Triggers>        
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

My problem is that my `GridView` don't refresh with this query.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: is your get call your page load? why not just use the postback of your click event since you're making all your code at server side.

Comment: But how can I just click in my radio button and call my pageload again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Ajax` Tretament - based on `UpdatePanel`, `Triggers` and `UpdateMode="Condition"`

You can use this code (Adjust your GridView and Id of your radio button on trigger)

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" >
</asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ModeUpdate="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
            <Columns>
                  ......
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>


       <asp:RadioButton ...../> 

    </ContentTemplate>


    <Triggers>
          <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="YourRadioButtonId" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Ok lucas i'am here if you need

Comment: The `EventName` of my `Trigger` is a reference to any event that exist in my RadioButton ? The event in my Radiobutton has to call Click ?

Comment: EventName="Click" is good, he is mapped to event for example Click or SelectIndexChanged etc;;;;

Comment: I got this error. `A control with ID 'rbBuscas' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'`. Strange error, because the id of my RadioButton is rbBuscas

Comment: Add your radion button to your Update Panel bottom of gridview

Comment: I tryied to put the radioButton before the `</ContentTemplate>` tag, but still the same error

Comment: rbBuscas must be id of your radiobutton, and add runat="server" to your control

Comment: I updated my question with the aspx code, where you can see the updatePanel

Comment: Add EventName="CheckedChanged" to your triggers

Comment: I put it now and the error `Can not find an event named 'Click' on associated control 'rdBuscas' for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'.`

Comment: I'am sorry Add EventName="CheckedChanged" to your trigger, because you have OnCheckedChanged="Click" _> and you must have delegate with Click Name

Comment: Lucas tell me answer speed, because i exit from my home

Comment: Work fine!  Whats the option to put on EventName ?

Comment: i'am happy that you solved your problem, EventName="CheckedChanged", because you arre mapped on CheckedChanged, just this Lucas, Lucas i come back tomorrow